# Wrap a row of blocks in the middle instead of end (CSS/JS/jQ)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can a row of inline-blocks be wrapped by a shrinking parent resulting in  equal (or almost equal) rows?

So instead of wrapping like this:

[image]

wrap like this:

[image]

And if there's an uneven number of blocks, like this:

[image]

Comment: What is causing your wrapping? By the arrows, I assume you're shrinking the width of the screen to cause the elements to wrap / stack? So essentially, you're asking how to display even numbers of columns on smaller screens?

Comment: @ObsidianAge a shrinking parent element is causing the wrapping to the child elements. I'm asking how to have equal number of blocks in each row. But if there's an uneven number of blocks in total, have the last row with 1 less block than the rest of the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that inserts `<br>` elements at the ends of each row. This code can be placed into a function to run whenever you need to wrap the blocks.

```
// Make sure that the last row of blocks doesn't have 2 less blocks than all
// the previous rows. Assume that all blocks are equal size.
var blocks = sharing.find('.btn');

//what's the parent width
var parentWidth = blocks.parent().width();

//how many blocks can fit in such a width
var maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow = Math.floor(parentWidth / blocks.outerWidth(true));

//repeatable code
var calcNumOfBlocksInLastRow = function(){
  var lastRowFull = blocks.length % maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow ? false : true;
  if (lastRowFull) {
    return maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow;
  } else {
    return blocks.length % maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow;
  }
}

//do we have more blocks than row's maximum?
if (blocks.length > maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow) {
  //how many blocks would the last row have
  var numOfBlocksInLastRow = calcNumOfBlocksInLastRow();

  //if the last row is missing more than 1 block, try with 1 less block in each row
  while (numOfBlocksInLastRow < maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow - 1) {
    maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow--;
    numOfBlocksInLastRow = calcNumOfBlocksInLastRow();
  }

  //insert <br> at the end of each row
  jQuery('<br>').insertAfter(blocks.filter(':nth-child(' + maxNumOfBlocksInOneRow + 'n)'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid `grid-template-columns` and @media (if you want to wrap by screen-width) or in JS with `docment.getElementById('bottomblocks').style.gridTemplateColumns` variable to achieve this. (If I understand correctly)

I wrote here an example with JS:
[https://jsfiddle.net/Lhbqdt2z/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhbqdt2z/13/)

You can learn about it where I started with it: [Coding Tech Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kVeCqQCxlk)

Or just from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Moz://a has a good examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it doesn't meet the requirements unfortunately. Also, kinda would like to stay away from CSS grid atm

Answer (score 0):

He is something fun I just wrote... Assuming you want an "enhanced wrap" behavior that wraps by the half of its childs, instead of the normal floating.

It's more an "essay" than a strong best practice answer. ;)

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
  $(".container div").css({"clear":"initial"});
  var wrapped = false;
  var wrappedAt = 0;
  var wrappedNtimes =0;
  var pos = $(".container div").first().offset();
  var n = $(".container div").length;

  $(".container div").each(function(index){
    if(!wrapped){

      if( ($(this).offset().top != pos.top)){
        console.log("Wrapped at "+index+" out of "+n);
        wrapped = true;
        wrappedAt = index;
        wrappedNtimes++;
      }
      pos=$(this).offset();
    }
  });

  if(wrapped){
    // Force enhanced wrapping... .oO(lol)
    console.log("--"+wrappedAt+"--");
    var half = Math.ceil(n/(wrappedNtimes+1));

    $(".container div").each(function(){
      if( $(this).index() != 0 && ($(this).index())%half == 0){
        $(this).css({"clear":"left"});  // zero-based.
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JaKoYa?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks, this is terrific! BUT, it fails after filling 2 rows with blocks. The behavior becomes erratic on the 3rd row onwards :)

Comment: If you want to apply it to many `.container`... You probably have to loop through them... and for each, loop throught the `div`. --- I wrote it just like that without much context. It's not a battlefield tested solution. You will have to adapt it.